# IndexError: tuple index out of range using PyInstaller and auto-py-to-exe with python 3.10

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a livrable.py to exe, I tried using auto-py-to-exe and pyinstaller but keep getting the same error "IndexError: tuple index out of range". I run a powershell in the same directory as my .py file, and I made sure to install all the packages used by my program in the same directory. I also tried to use dev versions of pyinstaller, but getting the same error.

Error in powershell

[image: Error in powershell]

Error in auto-py-to-exe

[image: Error in auto-py-to-exe]

Here is livrable :

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2
import statistics
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.morphology import binary_closing, binary_dilation, binary_erosion, binary_opening
from skimage.color import rgb2gray
import skimage.morphology as morpho
from PIL import Image
from scipy import ndimage
from skimage import data
from skimage.morphology import disk
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu, rank
from skimage.filters import threshold_multiotsu
from skimage.util import img_as_ubyte
from numpy import array
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.filedialog import *
from skimage import morphology
from skimage.segmentation import watershed
from skimage.feature import peak_local_max
from skimage import filters

def comptage(n,f,i) :
    if n < 10 :
        n = "000" + str(n)
    else :
        if n >=10 :
            if n < 100 :
                n = "00" +str(n)
            else :
                n = "0" + str(n)
    folder = f
    imname = i + n
    im = Image.open(folder + '\\' + imname + "_TRANS.tif")
    imDAPI = Image.open(folder + '\\' + imname + "_DAPI.tif")
    imGFP = Image.open(folder + '\\' + imname + "_GFP.tif")
    imtrans = array(im)
    imdapi = array(imDAPI)
    imgfp = array(imGFP)

    sobel = filters.sobel(imtrans)
    sobel1 = sobel>0.05
    sobel1 = binary_dilation(sobel1)
    imtrans1 = sobel1 * imtrans
    thresh = cv2.threshold(imtrans1, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
    cv2.fillPoly(imtrans1, cnts, [255,255,255])
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (4,4))
    mask = cv2.morphologyEx(imtrans1, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=5)

    imdapi1 = filters.sobel(imdapi)
    imdapi2 = imdapi1 >0.1
    imdapi3 = binary_opening(imdapi2)
    imdapi4 = imdapi * binary_closing(imdapi3)
    thresh1 = cv2.threshold(imdapi4, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    cnts1 = cv2.findContours(thresh1, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts1 = cnts1[0] if len(cnts1) == 2 else cnts1[1]
    cv2.fillPoly(imdapi4, cnts1, [255,255,255])
    kernel1 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (4,4))
    imdapi4 = cv2.morphologyEx(imdapi4, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=1)
    imdapi4 = cv2.bitwise_and(imdapi4, mask)

    imgfp1 = cv2.threshold(imgfp, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    imgfp2 = cv2.bitwise_and(imgfp1, mask)
    imdapigfp = imdapi4 * imgfp2

    CoefBeads = 1.2083459023
    stdrd = 0.0059145257

    NbBeads = np.mean(mask)/CoefBeads
    NbLiveCells = np.mean(imdapi4)/stdrd
    NbDeadCells = ndimage.label(imdapigfp)[1]
    NbTotalCells = NbLiveCells +NbDeadCells

    resimage = [imname , NbBeads , NbLiveCells , NbDeadCells , NbTotalCells]

    return resimage

#f = r"C:\Users\sleve\EVerZom\EVerZom EVZ - Documents\A_R&D interne\Axe 2_Production d'EVs\2021\20211102-BioBLu10c1bis-hASC\09 11 2021 Production 20211102-BioBLu10c1bis-hASC\t4"
# Récupère le root du fichier contenant les images
gui = tk.Tk()
gui.title('fichier')
gui.geometry("300x100")
def getEntry():
    global f
    f = myEntry.get()
    gui.destroy()
myEntry = tk.Entry(gui, width=40)
myEntry.pack(pady=20)
btn = tk.Button(gui, height=1, width=30, text="Chemin d'accès au fichier", command=getEntry)
btn.pack()
gui.mainloop()

#i = "13"
# Récupère le nom de l'image en le demandant dans une fenêtre à l'utilisateur
gui = tk.Tk()
gui.title('image')
gui.geometry("300x100")
def getEntry():
    global i
    i = myEntry.get()
    gui.destroy()
myEntry = tk.Entry(gui, width=40)
myEntry.pack(pady=20)
btn = tk.Button(gui, height=1, width=20, text="Nom de l'image", command=getEntry)
btn.pack()
gui.mainloop()

#debut = 1
#Récupère le rang de la première photo
gui = tk.Tk()
gui.title('Rang de la première photo')
gui.geometry("300x100")
def getEntry():
    global debut
    debut = myEntry.get()
    gui.destroy()
myEntry = tk.Entry(gui, width=40)
myEntry.pack(pady=20)
btn = tk.Button(gui, height=1, width=20, text="Num photo début", command=getEntry)
btn.pack()
gui.mainloop()

#fin = 13
#Récupère le rang de la dernière photo
gui = tk.Tk()
gui.title('Rang de la dernière photo')
gui.geometry("300x100")
def getEntry():
    global fin
    fin = myEntry.get()
    gui.destroy()
myEntry = tk.Entry(gui, width=40)
myEntry.pack(pady=20)
btn = tk.Button(gui, height=1, width=20, text="Num photo fin", command=getEntry)
btn.pack()
gui.mainloop()

#Récupère le nom que l'utilisateur veut donner au fichier résultat
gui = tk.Tk()
gui.title('Nom à donner au fichier résultat')
gui.geometry("300x100")
def getEntry():
    global nomfichier
    nomfichier = myEntry.get()
    gui.destroy()
myEntry = tk.Entry(gui, width=40)
myEntry.pack(pady=20)
btn = tk.Button(gui, height=1, width=20, text="Nom fichier résultat", command=getEntry)
btn.pack()
gui.mainloop()

debut = int(debut)
fin = int(fin)
resultat = []

for n in range(debut , fin+1) :
    resultat.append(comptage(n,f,i))

resultat = array(resultat)
print(resultat)
np.savetxt(nomfichier + '.csv', resultat, fmt='%s')
```

It runs properly on a python environment

Comment: Can you show us what `livrable.py` is?

Comment: Of course here it is :

Answer (score 1):

I've also encountered this same issue while converting a **python.py** to **.exe** format using Pyinstaller. After making several tries and several research I've got a result that **Python 3.10** doesn't allow you to build "**.py**" to "**.exe**" format.
I've tried the file building using **Python 3.8** and **Python 3.12**. Both of the versions were working pretty well and finally I've got **.exe**.
Try building the file using these two versions.

---

**Note**

Sometimes you may find another issue even if you use the above two version i'e After downloading **Python 3.8** or **Python 3.12** and after adding the path within **Edit the System Environment Variables**, the **Pyinsatller** may still redirect the path to the **Python 3.10** which is already available within the PC. If **Python 3.10** is not available within the PC, then it will definitely show an error.
To avoid this issue, Add the path of the Python Interpreter explicitly (**Python 3.8 or Python3.12**).
Follow the command given below to fix the issue:

```
"C:\Python312\python.exe" -m pyinstaller --onefile ./python.py
```

Make sure you have included all the dependencies

- PyInstaller
- Python (3.8 or 3.12)